# Dynamically adding rows to the Gridview in ASP.NET(C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, templatefield

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FileName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="" Text=""></asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

aspx.cs file

```
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(Select 
        FileUpload.FileName AS FileName,
        FileUpload.FilePath AS PATH,
        SubjectMaster.SubjectName AS Subject,
        MemberPersonalInformation.FirstName As SharedBy 
    from FileUpload",conn)
```

I need to print `FileName(As Hyperlink)`,`SharedBy`,`Subject` in the Grid how can I do that? 
I need to do something like this...But below approach not working

```
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();

        int i = 0;
        while (rdr.Read())
        {

            string fip = rdr["PATH"].ToString();
           HyperLink h1 = (HyperLink)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("Hyperlink1");
                h1.Text = rdr["FileName"].ToString();
                h1.NavigateUrl = "download.aspx?filepath=" + fip;

                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text = rdr["SharedBy"].ToString();
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text = rdr["Subject"].ToString();
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text = rdr["PATH"].ToString();
                //GridView1.Rows[i].Rows.Add(di);

              i++;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FileName">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("PATH")%>' Text='<%#Eval("FileName")%>'></asp:HyperLink>,
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SharedBy")+", "+ Eval("Subject")%>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
/asp:GridView>
```

In the cs you can bind the grid view with your query like this:

```
conn.Open();
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("your query");
SqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
GridView1.DataBind();
rdr.close();
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you are saying? actually I need to do the coding in .cs file